# Can't get button to work in Kivy

Tags: python-3.x, button, kivy

I am trying to get this button to work and can't figure out what is wrong. 
I could really use some help as i am new to kivy. When i run the code the button pops up but when you click on it nothing happens. Why won't it work?

By the way i know that nothing will happen once you get to the next page but right now i just want to get there.

Here is the full code and the kv file.

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.9.1')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput  
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class StartScreen(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
      super(StartScreen,self).__init__(**kwargs)
      self.StartGame = Button(text="Start Game")
      self.StartGame.bind(on_press=self.on_press)
      self.add_widget(self.StartGame)

def on_press(self,instance):

    return LoginScreen()

class LoginScreen(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LoginScreen,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 2



class MyApp(App):
 def build(self):
    return StartScreen()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

KV file

```
#:kivy 1.9.1



<StartScreen>:
  Label:
    font_size: 120
    center_x: root.width / 2
    top: root.top - 100
    text: "Starfire"



<LoginScreen>
  f_username: username 
  f_password: password 
    GridLayout:
    rows: 2
    padding: 5
    spacing: 5
    Label:
        text: "User Name:"
    TextInput:
        id: username
    Label:
        text: 'Password'
    TextInput:
        id: password
        password: True
```

Answer (score 0):

Returning a widget from the on_press method will not make it the root object.

```
def on_press(self,instance): 
    return LoginScreen() # will not do anything like you expected*
```

You need to look at popup and screenmanager:

https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html

https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.popup.html?highlight=popup#module-kivy.uix.popup

Choose what's suites you.

Answer (score 0):

this is a working example:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, SlideTransition


screen_manager = ScreenManager(transition=SlideTransition())


class RootScreen(Screen):

    settings_button = Button(text='Settings')
    settings_button.bind(on_press=screen_manager.switch_to(SettingsScreen())


class SettingsScreen(Screen):
    pass


class WifiApp(App):

    def build(self):
        screen_manager.add_widget(RootScreen(name='main'))
        screen_manager.add_widget(SettingsScreen(name='settings'))
        return screen_manager


if __name__ == '__main__':
    WifiApp().run()
```